# Css rule priority issue

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have following code:

```css
.wrap .sel{
  background-color: red;
}
.sel{
  background-color: blue;
}
select{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <select class='sel'>
    <option>CSS</option>
    <option>JS</option>
   </select> 
<div>
```

Why always the color get RED, even if I changing the rule's order in CSS section?

Thanks !

EDIT:
I know how to work with `!important`, I just asked this question to find out, how browser select the css rule.

Comment: Refer this post https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Look at [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the select .wrap .sel is more specific than .sel so it overrides .sel color definition.
same for select selector.
if you want them to override, you should make them more specific or add !important like "blue !important;"

Comment: look at http://plnkr.co/edit/gJ1b8giU36Tdi7gLupaS?p=preview example with !important

Comment: thanks, I asked this question to find out browser how exactly decide to selecting a css rule. could you please give me more details?

Comment: from MDN: "In the usual way, if you make a selector more specific, then you increase its priority." basically it means the more specific path you add or if you add an ID or the element type in addition to the class, you make it more specific. more specific->overrides less specific.. you can see it very clearly in chrome developer tools when you inspect an element (meaning you see all styles applied on element and their priorities)